# How to center text on a line in a flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

Ehi everyone, I am having issues centering on the C shaped line, positioned at the left of the picture. What is the proper way to do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=red!20, 
text width=5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
    \node[block, label={360:$O(1)$}] (init) {inizializza};
    \node[decision, below of=init, label={360:$O(1)$}] (cond) {condizione};
    \node[block, below of=cond, label={360:$O(f(n))$}] (corpo) {corpo del ciclo};
    \node[block, below of=corpo,label={360:$O(1)$}] (reinit) {re-inizializza};

    \path[line] (init) -- (cond);
    \path[line] (cond) -- (corpo);
    \path[line] (corpo) -- (reinit);
    \path[line] (reinit.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) -- node[midway]{$g(n)$ volte} ++(0,1) |- (cond.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Schematizzazione del costrutto \texttt{FOR}.}
    \label{fig:ciclofor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break the `|-` into two line segments.  Here is one way:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=red!20, 
text width=5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
    \node[block, label={360:$O(1)$}] (init) {inizializza};
    \node[decision, below of=init, label={360:$O(1)$}] (cond) {condizione};
    \node[block, below of=cond, label={360:$O(f(n))$}] (corpo) {corpo del ciclo};
    \node[block, below of=corpo,label={360:$O(1)$}] (reinit) {re-inizializza};

    \path[line] (init) -- (cond);
    \path[line] (cond) -- (corpo);
    \path[line] (corpo) -- (reinit);
    \path[line] (reinit.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) coordinate(A) -- node[midway]{$g(n)$ volte} (A|-cond) -- (cond.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Schematizzazione del costrutto \texttt{FOR}.}
    \label{fig:ciclofor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have to break up the `|-` at all. According to the tikz manual (sec. 17.8) when placing nodes along such a path the `midway` position (`pos=.5`) refers to the bend. That is, if you want to position a label at the middle of the first (vertical) half you need `pos=.25`. Similarly, `pos=.75` is the middle of the second half of the path.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=red!20,
text width=5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
    \node[block, label={360:$O(1)$}] (init) {inizializza};
    \node[decision, below of=init, label={360:$O(1)$}] (cond) {condizione};
    \node[block, below of=cond, label={360:$O(f(n))$}] (corpo) {corpo del ciclo};
    \node[block, below of=corpo,label={360:$O(1)$}] (reinit) {re-inizializza};

    \path[line] (init) -- (cond);
    \path[line] (cond) -- (corpo);
    \path[line] (corpo) -- (reinit);
    \path[line] (reinit.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[pos=.25]{$g(n)$ volte} (cond.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Schematizzazione del costrutto \texttt{FOR}.}
    \label{fig:ciclofor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I second the Emma answer :-), however, his code can be in this particular case of simple flowchart can be with use of package `chains` far more concise:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                calc, chains, 
                shapes,
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1cm, 
      start chain = A going below,
      base/.style = {draw, 
                     text width=5em, align=flush center,
                     on chain=A, join=by line},
  decision/.style = {base, diamond, fill=red!20,
                     aspect=1.2, inner sep=0pt},
     block/.style = {base, rectangle, rounded corners, 
                     fill=blue!20, minimum height=4em},
      line/.style = {-latex'},
                    ]
\node (init)  [block,    label=0:$O(1)$]    {inizializza};
\node (cond)  [decision, label=0:$O(1)$]    {condizione};
\node (corpo) [block,    label=0:$O(f(n))$] {corpo del ciclo};
\node (reinit)[block,    label=0:$O(1)$]    {re- inizializza};
%
\draw[line] (reinit.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[pos=0.25,left] {$g(n)$ volte} (cond) ;% borowed/stolen from Emma answer
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Schematizzazione del costrutto \texttt{FOR}.}
    \label{fig:ciclofor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I also replace deprecated `tikzsyle` with local set of nodes styles. In it for common features is defined style `base`. The result is similar:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not get answers, here is a quick and dirty way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=red!20,
text width=5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
    \node[block, label={360:$O(1)$}]                   (init) {inizializza};
    \node[decision, below of=init, label={360:$O(1)$}] (cond) {condizione};
    \node[block, below of=cond, label={360:$O(f(n))$}] (corpo) {corpo del ciclo};
    \node[block, below of=corpo,label={360:$O(1)$}]    (reinit) {re-inizializza};
    \node[coordinate] (lreinit) [left=15pt of reinit] {};
    \node[coordinate] (lcond)   [left=15pt of cond] {};

    \path[line] (init) -- (cond);
    \path[line] (cond) -- (corpo);
    \path[line] (corpo) -- (reinit);
%    \path[line] (reinit.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) -- node[midway]{$g(n)$ volte} ++(0,1) |- (cond.west);
    \draw[->,red] (reinit) -- (lreinit) -- node[midway, left]{$g(n)$ volte} (lcond) -- (cond) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Schematizzazione del costrutto \texttt{FOR}.}
    \label{fig:ciclofor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]